# Executors not starting with Jenkins on Google Container Engine

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to try out continuous deployment with Jenkins on Google Container Engine.

I have gone through https://cloud.google.com/solutions/jenkins-on-container-engine-tutorial and then https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery-jenkins-container-engine.

I have done it all twice to make sure I didn't miss anything in the tutorials, but still I have the same problem. The problem is in the second tutorial, under the section "Creating a Jenkins job". I follow all the steps, but my build job never starts. All I get in Jenkins is **Waiting for next available executor**.

[image]

Do you have any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Even though it is not in the tutorial, I have tried increasing number of nodes under "Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes -> Master" from 0. That does not seem to be the right way to go, since even though it now starts a build, I get an error about "docker: not found".

Answer (score 2):

Things started working once I added **jnlp** here:

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Cloud -> Kubernetes -> Defaults Provider Template Name